# SQL: Random query of row but sorted

Tags: sql, random

What I want to achieve is to get a random set of row everytime I queried the database but still sorted say alphabetically. Is it possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which RDBMS would this be (MySql, Oracle, Sql Server, etc?)

Comment: What database are you using?  Can you provide a query for the random rows?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using mySQL you could do something like this:

```
SELECT [ columns ]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [ columns ]
    FROM
    [ tablename ]
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT [ number of rows you want ]
) x
ORDER BY [ column you want to sort by ]
```

Comment: What I was about to type... +1

Comment: , or directly SELECT * FROM ( ...; no need to repeat [columns].

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using a subquery.  You don't specify the database you are using, but I assume you have some method for getting random rows:

```
select t.*
from (<your random subquery here>) t
order by col;
```

`col` is the column you want the results ordered by.

This is standard SQL so it should work with any database.